# Spatial data visualization level of detail

Tags: visualization

I have a 3D point cloud data set with different attributes that I visualize as points so far, and I want to have LOD based on distance from the set. I want to be able to have a generalized view from far away with fewer and larger points, and as I zoom in I want a more points correctly spaced out appearing automatically.

Kind of like this video below, behavior wise: http://vimeo.com/61148577

I thought one solution would be to use an adaptive octree, but I'm not sure if that is a good solution. I've been looking into hierarchical clustering with seamless transitions, but I'm not sure which solution I should go with that fits my goal.

Any ideas, tips on where to start? Or some specific method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The video you linked uses 2D metaballs. When metaballs clump together, they form blobs, not larger circles. Are you okay with that?

You should read an intro to metaballs before continuing. Just google 2D metaballs.

So, hopefully you've read about metaball threshold values and falloff functions. Your falloff function should have a *radius*--a distance at which the function falls to zero.

We can achieve an LOD effect by tuning the threshold and the radius. Basically, as you zoom out, increase radius so that points have influence over a larger area and start to clump together. Also, adjust threshold so that areas with insufficient density of points start to disappear.

I found this existing jsfiddle 2D metaballs demo and I've modified it to showcase LOD:

- LOD 0: Individual points as circles. (http://jsfiddle.net/TscNZ/370/)
- LOD 1: Isolated points start to shrink, but clusters of points start to form blobs. (http://jsfiddle.net/TscNZ/374/)
- LOD 2: Isolated points have disappeared. Blobs are fewer and larger. (change above URL to jsfiddle revision 377)
- LOD 3: Blobs are even fewer and even larger. (change above URL to jsfiddle revision 380)

As you can see in the different jsfiddle revisions, changing LOD just requires tuning a few variables:

```
threshold = 1,
max_alpha = 1,
point_radius = 10,
```

A crucial point that many metaballs articles don't touch on: you need to use a convention where only values *above* your threshold are considered "inside" the metaball. Then, when zoomed far out, you need to set your threshold value *above* the peak value of your falloff function. This will cause an isolated point to disappear completely, leaving only clumps visible.

Rendering metaballs is a whole topic in itself. This jsfiddle demo takes a very inefficient brute-force approach, but there's also the more efficient "marching squares".